# Error in Bash script to change folder/file permissions

Tags: bash, parsing, variables, cut

I don't know a lot about scripting, but I was attempting to write my own.

**Context:**

I have 2 servers. When server 1 (ubuntu server) automatically adds files to server 2 (synology) (through docker container) permissions of those files are wrong, so some applications I'm running can't access them.
I wanted to write a script that checks for permissions periodically and then changes them to what I want.
I've been messing with it for some days and this is what I've got for now:

```
#!/bin/bash
 
shopt -s nullglob

FOLDERS=(/volume1/files/videos/* /volume1/files/photos/*)

for folder in "${FOLDERS[@]}"; do
#    [[ -d "$folder" ]]
    if [ "$(stat -c '%a' "$folder")" != "755" ] || [ "$(stat -c '%U' "$folder")" != "my_user" ]
    then
#       echo "Change user permissions of $folder"
        chown -R my_user:users "$folder" && chmod 755 -R "$folder"
    fi
done

shopt -u nullglob
```

The problem whit this script is that when files (and not folders) are added it won't detect those files.
So I change the script to this: (find files in directories and the change top directory's permissions recursively)

```
#!/bin/bash
    
    shopt -s nullglob
    
    FOLDERS=(/volume1/files/videos/* /volume1/files/photos/*)
    FILES=(/volume1/files/videos/*/*.mp4 /volume1/files/photos/*/*/*.jpg)
    
    for file in "${FILES[@]}"; do
        if [ "$(stat -c '%a' "$file")" != "755" ] || [ "$(stat -c '%U' "$file")" != "my_user" ]
    then
#       echo "$file" | (cut -d "/" -f5)     # --> WORKS PERFECTLY
        rootfolder=$(("$file") | (cut -d "/" -f5))
#       echo "$rootfolder"      # --> ERROR: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

#       chown -R my_user:users "$rootfolder" && chmod 755 -R "$rootfolder"
        echo "chown -R my_user:users "$rootfolder" && chmod 755 -R "$rootfolder" "
    fi
done
```

When I add **"$file" | (cut -d "/" -f5)** into a variable **"rootfolder"** (*"/volume1/files/videos"* and *"/volume1/files/photos"*, I'm getting this error when executing the script:

```
./modify_media_permissions-test.sh: line 12: /volume1/files/videos/my_video.mp4: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Tried different thing, but can't resolve it.
Could someone help me further?
I know it is probably not the best and most efficient script, but I'm learning :)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `("$file") | (cut -d "/" -f5)` is the problem. `"$file"` will try and execute the file you're iterating over rather than output its name for `cut` to work on. You want `echo "$file"`, not just `"$file"`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply @Aaron! Adding "echo" did the trick! I removed those brackets as well. Thanks for your help

Comment: And you should definitely remove those brackets, you're opening subshells for no reason and making an habit of it would significantly impact performances. Brackets aren't just a grouping operator in `bash`.  More info [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html).

Comment: @Aaron : You don't need `echo`, since you could equally well write `cut -d "/" -f5 <<<$file`).

Comment: Is there an easy way to verify if the output of the current loop is identical to the result of the previous loop? Tried with an "if" statement, but I'm a bit confused on the output/index, etc..  `if [ "${FILES[$file-1]}" != "${FILES[$file]}" ]`